# If a positive decreasing function satisfies $f(0)=1$ and $f''\le f$ on $[0,1)$, then $f'(0)\ge-\sqrt{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

> Let, $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function defined on $(-1, 1)$ and $f(0) = 1$. Let, $f(x) ≥ 0$, $f'(x) ≤ 0$ and $f''(x) ≤ f(x)$ for all $x ≥ 0$. Show that, $f'(0) ≥ -√2$.

I am telling you what I did.

First, I noted that $-√2$ is somehow a bit odd to suddenly appear in such a situation, but then realized that $-√2$ is the minimum value of a function of the form $(sinx + cosx)$ ! This realization caused me to think of a function $f(x)$ such that it is decreasing (as $f'(x) ≤ 0$), and trigonometric.

And, the words "twice differentiable" excited me: we know that a trigonometric sine or cosine function gives back somewhat the negative of the original function on twice differentiation.

So, by careful choice, I selected the function $f(x) = \cos p√2x - \sin p√2x$, where $p$ is a real number belonging to $[0, 1]$.

Then, $f'(x) = -p√2(\sin p√2x + \cos p√2x)$, which is clearly $≤ 0$ (and hence satisfies the problem.) We also find that $f'(0) = -p√2$ and as $1 ≥ p ≥ 0$, $-√2 ≤ p√2 ≤ 0$ (hence shown!)

You may note that for this function, $f''(x) = -2p²f(x) ≤ f(x)$, equality holding if $p = 0$ or $f(x) = 0$.

Now, is my method correct? I, actually, do not know how to work with these inequalities in derivatives so I just used my intuition to get this function and hopefully it should work!

Comment: i do not understand how did you get that less than or equal to sign and that not so neatly written square root symbol.. just by using keyboard? :O

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find LATEX anywhere. Maybe I went blind but yeah, only keyboard!

Comment: There is help on this site about LaTeX formatting. Try typing `$` before and after each math formula to get started.

Comment: I think I will use my first 3-4 questions and answers trying to use LaTeX. I am new to this site and LaTeX is somewhat daunting.